# Equivalent meaning of double arrow in logic

Tags: logic

I have come across this question, where I need to find a logically equivalent formula in which  formula in which ∧, ⇒and ⇐⇒ do not occur.
Here is the formula:
¬((p ∧ q) ⇐⇒ r)

I have figured out the first part, however I can't figure out how to find another way to express the ⇐⇒ r.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What did you figure out for the "first part"?

Comment: The two logical operators "or" and "not" are truth-functionally complete. So it is possible to express your statement containing "not", "and", and "equivalent to" into a longer statement containing only "or" and "not". Is that what you want? [If so there are standard ways to proceed...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\lnot((p \land q) \iff r)$
We can express $a \iff b \equiv (a \implies b) \land (b \implies a)$
So our above equation become $\lnot(((p\land q)\implies r) \land (r \implies (p \land q)))$
We can express $a \implies b \equiv \lnot a \lor b$
So,
$= \lnot(((p\land q)\implies r) \land (r \implies (p \land q)))$
$= \lnot((\lnot(p \land q) \lor r) \land (\lnot r \lor (p \land q)))$
$= \lnot((\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r) \land (\lnot r \lor p) \land (\lnot r \lor q))$

Using De Morgan's law,
$= \lnot(\lnot p \lor \lnot q \lor r) \lor \lnot(\lnot r \lor p) \lor \lnot(\lnot r \lor q)$

Comment: Perfect, that is great, thank you so much for your help